# div height 100% not showing on page

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to make a div 100% of the screen height, and I can't get it to work. My wrapper is the first and last thing in the `<body>`, and it's height is 100%. I have another div inside this, and it'd height is also 100%. It does not show on the page at all. Why might this be happening?

Comment: Have you specified a `width` for the wrapper?

Comment: Please provide a fiddle.

Comment: make sure it has WIDTH set too. If you don't set it, your browser will think it's 0px and not show it

Comment: It may be the case that your body has height 0, and the heights are 100% of 0. Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XCeBq/1)

Comment: Try to make 'html {height:100%;}' aswell

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must have `height: 100%;` on the HTML, BODY and DIV tags.

```
html, body, div
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/RYmvX/

You can see in the example that only the div has the background color, it fills the entire window.

Comment: Works perfectly, although for some reason, there's always a few extra pixels on the bottom beyond the screen (no bottom margin)

Comment: In my example or on your page?

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks mine. Seems like something I will be able to fix, only 20 lines or so to worry about in the CSS file.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks Turns out I had padding on, fixed.

Comment: Good job :) It's often things like that.

Answer (score 1):

Your body tag might still have a margin. Try setting `margin:0` on the body tag.